# Use WSL bash as vscode terminal with anaconda

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have anaconda setup with all my libs in Windows already.   Is there anyway to use WSL bash as the vscode terminal, but with  python.exe and conda.exe from the anaconda install?   I have bash added as a terminal already but I don't want to reinstall python inside WSL.

Comment: You can use python.exe as usual, e.g. `/mnt/c/Python/python.exe foo.py`